# how to place my logo above navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have the logo on the navbar itself but i want it above the navbar so that it stays on the left top corner. can someone help?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/LOGO HERE" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                </a>    
                  </div>
```

this is what I have.

Comment: I assume you're using Bootstrap 3, given the classes used?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/LOGO HERE" Width="100" Height="100" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work as expected. The navbar was on top and the logo came below.